# Why is std::borrow::Borrow not implementet for every Type?

Tags: rust, traits

On the documentation it is stated that

```
impl<T> Borrow<T> for T where
    T: ?Sized,
```

I would read this:

> This Trait is implemented for every Type, even unsized ones.

Is this correct?

I got the error message:
the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<T>` is not implemented for `&num_complex::Complex<f64>`

which I can't make sense of.

(I do not want to post the whole code, I just want some clarification about which types implement std::borror::Borrow)

Comment: Where did you find `impl<T> Borrow<T> for T where T: ?Sized`, it seems to me that rather `impl<T> Borrow<T> for &T where T: ?Sized` is correct. Yet this does not explain your error message, maybe you should reveal more of your code.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/borrow.rs.html#213-215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to recognize is that in the blanket `impl` there is only one `T` and it has to represent the *same* type in both places:

```
impl<T> Borrow<T> for T
    where T: ?Sized
```

implements *for each type `T`, only the specific trait `Borrow<T>`*. `i64` implements `Borrow<i64>`, `String` implements `Borrow<String>`, etc. When we instantiate this with `T = &num_complex::Complex<f64>`, what trait is implemented?

```
impl Borrow<&num_complex::Complex<f64>> for &num_complex::Complex<f64>  // (not compilable code, just illustrative)
```

In words, you can borrow a `&Complex<f64>` *as* a `&Complex<f64>`, but you can't borrow it as any arbitrary `T` (which wouldn't make much sense, anyway).

You're using this in some generic code where `T` can be anything, so the blanket `impl` of `Borrow<T> for T` doesn't apply. You can probably fix this by adding a trait bound:

```
where num_complex::Complex<f64>: Borrow<T>
```

which means that `Complex<f64>` itself implements `Borrow<T>`, or

```
where for<'a> &'a num_complex::Complex<f64>: Borrow<T>
```

which means that any reference to `Complex<f64>` implements `Borrow<T>`. Depending on your actual code either or both of these may work due to autoref/autoderef.